# BASH VARIABLE ADEED AFTER SQLITE3 LIKE CLAUSE

Tags: bash, sqlite, if-statement, variables, clause

I have a question about an sqlite3 command that im trying to insert inside my script

`if [[ -n $(tail -z 600 /var/log/pihole.log | grep  "$IP" | wc -c) ]];then`

`sudo -u pihole sqlite3 /etc/pihole/pihole-FTL.db 'DELETE FROM network WHERE hwaddr LIKE "$MAC"'`

`fi`

But soon i run my program it actually doesn't do what it was made for !

I already try whit a real mac address instead of the variable $MAC and it works !

So my question is how can i actually attach a variable in this particular bash command and of my script !

Thank-you in advance really appreciated !

Comment: Strings in sql should be using single quotes, not double quotes. The latter is used to quote identifiers like table and column names. (sqlite sometimes accepts them but it's not dependable as behavior can vary depending on how it was built and what the contents of the string are).

Comment: Yea Leonardo confirmed what u are telling ! Thank u so much guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is the usage of single quotes: in bash variables are not expanded in single quotes. You can solve this by either using double quotes or mixing single and double quotes (ensuring the variable you want expanded is in double quotes):

```
$ MAC=1111
$ echo "DELETE FROM network WHERE hwaddr LIKE \"$MAC\""
DELETE FROM network WHERE hwaddr LIKE "1111"
$ echo 'DELETE FROM network WHERE hwaddr LIKE '"\"$MAC\""
DELETE FROM network WHERE hwaddr LIKE "1111"
```